# Error when building Siri Intent on Apple Watch

Tags: watchos, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I want to create a Siri Intent for the Apple Watch. My application builds successfully, but when I try to install it I get the error "App name cannot be installed. This app is not created for this device".

The full error:

```
 Failed to install the app on the device. Domain:
 com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError Code: 3002 User Info: {
     DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-03-11 04:12:34 +0000";
     IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
     NSURL = "file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-ctbasntmprtyokayuvxndsjljacb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/";
 }
 -- (translation) "App name" cannot be installed. Reason: This app is not created for this device.
 -- “アプリ名”をインストールできません Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code: 6 Failure Reason: このアプリはこのデバイス用に作成されていません。 Recovery Suggestion: This app
 was not built to support this device family; app is compatible with (
     1 ) but this device supports (
     4 )
 -- This app was not built to support this device family; app is compatible with (
     1 ) but this device supports (
     4 ) Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain Code: 10 User Info: {
     FunctionName = MIIsApplicableToCurrentDeviceFamilyWithError;
     LegacyErrorString = DeviceFamilyNotSupported;
     SourceFileLine = 86; }
 --
 
 Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
     "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
     "device_isWireless" = 1;
     "device_model" = "Watch6,2";
     "device_osBuild" = "10.3.1 (21S651)";
     "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.watchos";
     "dvt_coredevice_version" = "355.24";
     "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.100.58";
     "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
     "launchSession_state" = 1;
     "launchSession_targetArch" = "arm64_32";
     "operation_duration_ms" = 929;
     "operation_errorCode" = 6;
     "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError.3002.IXUserPresentableErrorDomain";
     "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
     "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
     "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 1;
     "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
     "param_debugger_type" = 1;
     "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
     "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.watchos";
     "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
     "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
     "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
     "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
     "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
     "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
     "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
     "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
     "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
     "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
     "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
     "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
     "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
     "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
     "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
     "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
     "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
     "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
     "param_install_style" = 0;
     "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
     "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
     "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
     "param_launcher_style" = 0;
     "param_launcher_substyle" = 2;
     "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
     "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.app-extension";
     "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
     "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
     "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
     "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
     "sdk_canonicalName" = "watchos10.2";
     "sdk_osVersion" = "10.2";
     "sdk_variant" = watchos; }
 --
 
 
 System Information
 
 macOS Version 14.3.1 (Build 23D60) Xcode 15.2 (22503) (Build 15C500b)
 Timestamp: 2024-03-11T13:12:34+09:00
```

How can I avoid this error?
Thank you for your support.

**Environment**

- MacOS 14.3.1
- WatchOS 10.3.1
- Xcode 15.2

  - Xcode 15.3 has a bug, so it is set to 15.2.